# Setting a Coverage Threshold using Emma and Ant

Tags: ant, code-coverage, emma

I'm using Emma in my ant build to perform coverage reporting.  For those that have used Emma, is there a way to get the build to fail if the line coverage (or any type of coverage stat) does not meet a particular threshold?  e.g. if the line coverage is not 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box.

However, the [`report.metrics`](http://emma.sourceforge.net/reference/ch03s02.html#prop-ref.report.metrics) property or attribute of `<report></report>` can be set for `name, class, method, block`, and `line`.  See [Coverage Metrics](http://emma.sourceforge.net/reference/ch02s04.html) in the Emma reference.

Use a plain-text report then a regexp filter to set up a fail condition.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an ant task to do this.

You should be able to find all the information you need on my [EmmaCheck site](http://mchr3k.github.com/emmacheck/).